# Integrating/differentiating the signum function correctly

Tags: integration, derivatives

I was having a look into the signum function on Wikipedia, [and it gives the definition of it as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function#Definition):
$$sgn(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, & x>0 \\
0, & x=0 \\
-1, & x<0
\end{cases}
$$

However, if I integrate this function for all $x$, I wind up with $|x|+c$ (assuming that the constant of integration is the same for each condition).
$$\int sgn(x)\,dx=
\begin{cases}
\int 1\,dx, & x>0 \\
\int 0\,dx, & x=0 \\
\int -1\,dx, & x<0
\end{cases}
\\=
\begin{cases}
x, & x>0 \\
0, & x=0 \\
-x, & x<0
\end{cases}
+c
\\=
\begin{cases}
x, & x\ge0 \\
-x, & x<0
\end{cases}
+c
\\= |x|+c
$$

If I differentiate $|x|+c$, however, I get the result of $\frac{|x|}{x}$ which assumes x is not zero, but is different from the definition. Wikipedia mentions that this definition is true for $x\ne0$; but how would I return to the original definition from the derivative - assuming the integration was correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,  $|x|$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$, so you can't hope to retrieve anything there. If $f$ is a general (not necessarily continuous) $L^1_{loc}$-function (i.e. integrable over compact intervals), then defining $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\textrm{d}t,$ it's only true that $F'(x)=f(x)$ holds *almost everywhere*. In your case, you get the conclusion for every $x\neq 0$.

If you look at the usual proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus, it relies heavily on the fact that it deals with the integration of *continuous* functions.